# Bind control's ID property to object property

Tags: asp.net

I have the following repeater control, which is bound to collection of DashboardPage objects. DashboardPage has the following properties: **Name, Pagenumber** .

```
<asp:Repeater ID="reportPages" runat="server">           
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton    runat="server" onclick="ImageButton_Click" 
        ImageUrl="<%# GetImagePath(Container.DataItem) %>" 
        onmouseover="<%# GetMouseOverEventString(Container.DataItem) %>"
        onmouseout="<%# GetMouseOutEventString(Container.DataItem) %>"
         />
      </ItemTemplate>

      <SeparatorTemplate>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
      </SeparatorTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
```

I want to bind ImageButton's ID property to Name property of DashboardPage object, something like this

```
ID="<%# Eval('Name') %>"
```

But an exception is thrown:

> The ID property of a control can only be set using the ID attribute in the tag and a simple value.

I need the ID property of the image, because I have a client side script which changes the image, using the it's ID. Is there a way around this?

Thanks for replies

Regards
Gagik Kyurkchyan

Comment: why is it that you don't have  ID=YourIMageID on your image button

Comment: why not use CssClass or class or custom attribute instead of ID, NOTE: if your using id on repeater items, id will prefixed with the container's id plus underscores depending on the levels

Comment: Instead of using the databind #, have you tried to use =? <%= Eval('Name') %>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have found you cannot dynamically set the ID of a server control you need to find an alternative way of referencing your image using JavaScript. There are three ways I can think of:

1. Set the CssClass property of the control and use that instead. It's a little more inefficient to find a control by class rather than ID using DOM, but that is probably negligible in the real world.
2. Wrap your image in a standard `DIV`. and set the ID on the container `DIV`. You can then use something like jQuery to go `$("#divid img")...`
3. Use a standard `<img>` tag (with no `runat="server"`) rather than an `asp:Image` control. You can then set the ID on that without issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ItemDataBound to set the ID.

**CODEBEHIND:**

```
protected void myRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    var textbox = e.Item.FindControl("myTextBox");
    textbox.ID = "myTextBox" + (e.name).toString(); /*ToString() method can be unnecessary in some cases.*/
}
```

**REPEATER:**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="BehaviorCustomizeRepeater_ItemDataBound">
/*other stuffs*/
</asp:Repeater>
```