# The server tag is not well formed error while using repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have used repeater and in which i have below control :-

```
 <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hdnRecConfinementType<%#Eval("CountNumber")%>" value='<%#Eval("RecConfType")%>' class="recConfType" >
```

but it gives me run time error like :-

> The server tag is not well formed.

I need to use id like shown in above control i cant change it!

Comment: `"hdnRecConfinementType<%#Eval("CountNumber")%>"` <- double quotes inside the Eval?

Comment: yes it is required else it throws error

Comment: have you tried other way around, `"hdnRecConfinementType<%#Eval('CountNumber')%>"`. .NET server tags usually require double quotes.

Comment: yes i have tried but no success

Comment: you should also swap the value attr to `"<%#Eval('RecConfType')%>"`

Comment: no buddy it also does not work

Comment: why not do string concatenation?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the error by correcting the single & double quotes like this:-

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" value='<%# Eval("Section") %>' 
       id='<%# "hdnRecConfinementType" + Eval("EmployeeID")%>' />
```

But, it'll throw an error like this:-

> The ID property of a control can only be set using the ID attribute
>   in the tag and a simple value.

Since you can't change the `Id` of a control dynamically. If you don't want to use this control at server side then remove the `runat="server"` attribute and it will work fine otherwise you will have to take any alternative approach as explained in following answers:-

[Answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1191589/1529657), [Answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8558935/1529657)